# How to count days quantity

Tags: c#, datetime, time, timespan

I have check in year, month, day and check out year, moth, day. I can not solve problem how i can count how many days in this range

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var d1 = new DateTime(year1, month1, day1);
var d2 = new DateTime(year2, month2, day2);
TimeSpan t = d2 - d1;
var elapsedDays = t.Days;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
TimeSpan difference = endTime.Subtract(startTime); 
int numDays = difference.Days;
```

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting a `DateTime` (or a `DateTimeOffset`) from another will result in a `TimeSpan`. The `TimeSpan` structure has a `TotalDays` property which should give you what you're looking for.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) a link to the MSDN page for `TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(new DateTime(endYear, endMonth, endDay) - new DateTime(startYear, startMonth, startDay)).TotalDays
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime checkin //set to checkin date
DateTime checkout //set to checkout date
TimeSpan ts = checkout.Subtract(checkin);
int dayDifference = ts.TotalDays; //this is your days
```

Comment: .Days will give you 3 in the instance that the total timespan is 34 days.